# Parsing list items from html with Go

Tags: go

I want to extract all list items (content of each `<li></li>`) with Go. Should I use regexp to get the `<li>` items or is there any other library for this?

My intention is to get a list or array in Go that contains all list item from a specific html web page. How should I do that?

Comment: Perhaps the [html package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html) can be of use?

Comment: Do you want to scrape whole websites?

Comment: Don't try [parsing HTML with regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). In general think twice before using regexp for just about anything, it has it's place but far too many people jump to it for every single thing they do.

Comment: @DaveC That is exactly why I started this question, to find if there is any other more appropriate method. I don't understand all the down votes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use the [golang.org/x/net/html package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html).
It's not in the Go standard packages, but instead in the [Go Sub-repositories](https://golang.org/pkg/#subrepo). (The sub-repositories are part of the Go Project but outside the main Go tree. They are developed under looser compatibility requirements than the Go core.)

There is [an example](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#example-Parse) in that documentation that may be similar to what you want.

If you need to stick with the Go standard packages for some reason, then
for "typical HTML" you can use [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder).

Both packages tend to use an `io.Reader` for input. If you have a `string` or `[]byte` variable you can wrap them with `strings.NewReader` or `bytes.Buffer` to get an `io.Reader`.

For HTML it's more likely you'll come from an `http.Response` body
(make sure to close it when done).
Perhaps something like:

```
    resp, err := http.Get(someURL)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    doc, err := html.parse(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Recursively visit nodes in the parse tree
    var f func(*html.Node)
    f = func(n *html.Node) {
        if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
            for _, a := range n.Attr {
                if a.Key == "href" {
                    fmt.Println(a.Val)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
            f(c)
        }
    }
    f(doc)
}
```

Of course, parsing fetched web pages won't work for pages that modify their own contents with JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: Note, I blanked wrt the existence of the `golang.org/x/net/html` package as Go project HTML parser so a previous version of this answer only mentioned the Go standard `encoding/xml` package (which I've used in the past for trivial HTML decoding when I wanted/needed to stick with standard packages).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way I found to solve this.

If you're trying to extract the text after the `li` element you first find the `li` element and then **move the tokenizer to the very next element** which will be the text (hopefully). You may have to use some logic if the next element is an anchor, span, etc.

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
if err!=nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

z := html.NewTokenizer(bufio.NewReader(resp.Body))
for {
    tt := z.Next()
    switch tt {
    case html.ErrorToken:
        return
    case html.StartTagToken:
        t := z.Token()
        swith t.Data {
        case "li":
            z.Next()
            t = z.Token()
            fmt.Println(t.Data)
        }
    }
}
```

but really, you should just use `github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery`